# Elixir's dynamo web framework

Tags: sqlite, elixir

I found [here](http://johan.heapsource.com/post/54044725297/elixirs-dynamo) Elixir's dynamo example with postgres. I just wonder how it would be possible to change the postgres to Sqllite database? Are there any more examples how to use Dynamo, databases and JavaScript UI's like dojo?

Answer (score 3):

Dynamo was pretty much a proof of concept and we are short on examples. I would look for projects like Phoenix which are gaining more traction now. For the database, Elixir's Ecto is the main tool but currently it only supports PostgreSQL.